# How to add a properly scaled y axis to a stacked d3 bar chart

Tags: d3.js, svg

I've been working with Mike Bostock's stacked bar chart (here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4679202).

I've successfully made a number of modifications, but what I'm stuck on is trying to add a y axis with ticks and properly scaled values.

I thought it would simply be done by using this:

```
var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y2) //define ticks
    .orient("right").ticks(5);
```

However, that results in the values for only ONE set of the stack being used for the entire Y axis.  This results in an incorrect scale. The values for the range of all stacks COMBINED needs to be used to determine the range of values I believe.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing? To sum the range of all the columns.

If not, how would I write a function to set the range based on the values in all 4 columns?

Here is a working JSfiddle of what I have now (which is incorrect):
https://jsfiddle.net/1jhm7ths/

Comment: A plnkr or jsFiddle with your code would be helpful to understand your problem better. As a wild, blind guess, I would say this has someting to do with the `domain` of your scale...

Comment: @HuguesStefanski It's pretty similar to what the original is, but I have added a link for you to see what exactly I'm doing.

Comment: You can see in the example, the Y axis range is set from 0 to 14,000.  However, it is pulling those numbers just from the blue column which ranges from 0 to 14,000.  With the blocks stacked, it should be scaling from something like 0 to ~40,000.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you tried to achieve, you need to compute your range based on your stacked data and not the original ones. I [updated your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysauj0o3/1/) with the following modification on line 92:

```
y2.domain([0, d3.max(dataByGroup, function(d) { return d3.sum(d.values, function(v) {return v.value;}); })]); //added
```

What this does is taking each group, computing the sum of all values, and the taking the max of the sums.

On a side note, I would discourage learning d3 v3 and try to focus on the [v4](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.0.0) for longer term support, latest functionalities, modulariy, and a ton of other advantages.

Comment: Something still isn't correct on the scaling though. If you look to the right, the first tick is 20,000.  However, the largest blue bar is actually 14,000; and it is showing ABOVE the 20,000.

Comment: And yes, it is unfortunate that a lot of the good examples are written on versions v2 and v3.  I would prefer v4, but unlike most languages, this one is NOT backwards compatible.  So a lot of these won't work at all on v4.

Comment: Well, if you mean to use your second scale (y2) as your base scale, you basically need to go through the whole example, and use y2 where y1 is used, taking into account the fact that you have to use the valueOffset to compute your height. I do not have enough time to go through that right now, I hope it leads you on the right path.

Comment: An [here](https://bl.ocks.org/DimsumPanda/689368252f55179e12185e13c5ed1fee) is a v4 example of stacked bar chart :-)

Comment: Still not able to determine where your example has gone wrong.  If you take a look at the data in the file, it's pretty obvious what the results should look like.  We can't have values on the right axis that don't match up with the data.  Is it perhaps adding the max values for each column, instead of the max value of each data point?